# Memory usage on exception in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am in a position to save user details into db, and user name must be unique one, so that i can manually write logic to check whether the given username already exist in db or not, and otherwise I can set username field as unique in db, while saving duplicate username it will return a unique field exception. So that i can understand it from exception. I need to know which is the best practice, in terms of performance and memory usage.

Comment: Checking for duplicates manually doesn't work. Between the check and the insertion, another instance of the script can insert the same name and you'll end up with duplicates. Always rely on the database for keeping the values unique in the column.

Comment: Ohh that's a point, thanks

Comment: mark the column as unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend setting the column as unique as already noted.

```
const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
});
```

However, listening in on unique constraint errors from the database should be the last line of defense for your application. Just because there is a case where async timing may bypass your custom validator, I'd recommend setting up a validator for a unique constraint that is expected to be violated more frequently in your application.

More on this has been discussed here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2640